# Leaflet: Layer disappears on some zoom-levels

Tags: leaflet

On this Leaflet application I show all available bus stops in Denmark.

http://drivetime.mapicture.dk/stops

The strange thing is, that if you zoom down to one of the last 4 zoom levels, the layer with these bus stops simply disappears. They reappear when you zoom out again.

The bus stops are made as a single layer retrieved through a WMS request to our Geoserver. The entire javascript code is actually pretty simple, so I have trouble finding out, what causes this behavior.

```
function CurrentStopsMap(mapNode, zoomSettings) {
  var self = this;

  self.mapNode = mapNode;
  self.zoomSettings = zoomSettings;

  self.mapquest = new L.TileLayer('http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: "©<a href='http://openstreetmap.org/' target='_blank'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Tiles Courtesy of <a href='http://open.mapquest.com' target='_blank'>MapQuest</a>",
    subdomains: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
  });

  self.regions = new L.TileLayer.WMS("http://backend.mapicture.dk:8080/geoserver/mapicture/wms", {
    layers: 'mapicture:region',
    format: 'image/png',
    styles: 'regions',
    transparent: false
  });

  self.stops = new L.TileLayer.WMS("http://backend.mapicture.dk:8080/geoserver/mapicture/wms", {
    layers: 'mapicture:stops',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true
  });

  self.map = new L.Map(mapNode, {
    center: new L.LatLng(zoomSettings.lat, zoomSettings.lon),
    zoom: zoomSettings.level,
    layers: [self.mapquest, self.stops],
    zoomControl: true
  });

  L.control.layers({
    "Kort": self.mapquest,
    "Områder": self.regions
  }, {
    "Stoppesteder": self.stops
  }).addTo(self.map);
}

var zoom = {
  lat: 56.24,
  lon: 10.68,
  level: 7
};
var map = new CurrentStopsMap('map', zoom)
```

Comment: Don't you need to fix all the 404 errors on load first?

Comment: Ahh sorry - I've just made an update on the server that obviously took down the Geoserver daemon...

Comment: Now I got the geoserver up and running again with the entire server upgraded. And that actually took care of the problem with disappearing bus stops. So it was actually a Geoserver problem. :-)

Comment: Leaflet for some reason was trying to load tiles with a decimal zoom layer for me, which was giving 404s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a problem with the Geoserver daemon.